# How to delete combobox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, code-behind

As the question ask above, I have create `ComboBox` dynamically from code behind.

The code as below (this code is inside `BtnAddComboBox_Click`)

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.ItemsSource = salesman2;
comboBox.Name = "cbSalesman";

Button button = new Button();
button.Width = 50;
button.Name = "btnDelete";
button.Height = 30;
button.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
button.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnDeleteCB_Click);


grid.Children.Add(comboBox);
grid.Children.Add(button);

stackPanel.Children.Add(grid);
```

And I have a `Button` name `AddComboBox` at my XAML (the blue button). when user click on the button. the New ComboBox will be added along with the `DELETE BUTTON` named `btnDelete` beside it. so that's means every comboBox will have its own delete button. it does not have max number of `ComboBox` so it will keep adding the new ComboBox whenever user click the button.

The problem is when I click the `btnDelete`. It will delete all the comboBox added (since it have the same name I guess)

This is my delete method:

```
private void btnDeleteCB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = FindChildControl<StackPanel>(this,"spSalesmanCombobox") as StackPanel;
    stackPanel.Children.Remove(comboBox);
}
```

what I want is when I click the `btnDelete`, only the `ComboBox` beside it will deleted. How can I do that ? Is it possible to do it ?

I want to the delete the `ComboBox` itself. not the selected item / items inside it.

Comment: You should really consider digging into MVVM

Comment: *"delete the ComboBox itself"* - then you have to supply this info somehow. E.g. using attached property which you set when adding a button to point to a referenced combobox. A better approach would be indeed MVVM, where you don't operate with controls anymore, but with collections of view model, which would be easy to add/remove/visualize.

Comment: @thatxx both comments are good advice. Adding those view models to a collection and have a UserControl that represents the visual elements you are adding manually in code behind. Once you get a feel for that, the MVVM approach to things will begin to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. It will delete the Grid in which the Combobox and the Button is in. While leaving all others untouched. (I couldnt verify this code as i dont have an IDE right now)

```
    private void btnDeleteCB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grd = (sender as Button).Parent as Grid; //sender is button -> Parent is your grid
        stackPanel.Children.Remove(grd);  //remove that grid from the Stackpanel that contans them all
    }
```

Generally i would like to mention that WPF is designt to be used with MVVM where you do not have to manipulate the gui like this. Its a little bit harder to learn than the Windows forms way using the codebehind but will payoff after a while

Comment: thank you sir! its working. I should really learn harder. I'm new to this so its very tough for me. thank you for your help and advice :)

Comment: Glad this helped you out :)
make sure to mark it as answer for others to find